# Java.lang.SecurityException:SECURE PERMISSION in android?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Iam getting this error on my log

```
07-06 06:22:07.419: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2618): java.lang.SecurityException: SECURE PERMISSION: Neither user 10070 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS.
```

I used like this

in activity file

```
private static final String SECURE_SETTINGS = android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS;
mContext.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(SECURE_SETTINGS,
        "BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission");
```

in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

Why does it give error?

Comment: What Sdk target version are you using? Also, what are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: Iam using Android 1.5.Actually Iam experimenting on BLUETOOTH_ON or OFF by using 
android.provider.Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),
    android.provider.Settings.Secure.BLUETOOTH_ON,1);
For this purpose i used permission lines in activity and manifest file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission is not available to apps which aren't part of the firmware because secure settings are designed to be secured against modification by third party apps.

Comment: How can i use

android.provider.Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.BLUETOOTH_ON,1); 
this statement in my code without permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can only read this settings if your phone doesn't have root access. To enable bluetooth you can use this references http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html.

However, this is above sdk5... I'm not really sure if it is a good idea to use bluetooth with sdk3. I also wanted to do an app which uses bluetooth and I had to switch my target level to above 2.0.1 because bluetooth below this sdk is not supported very well.

Comment: Iam using firmware version 1.7.7 .In Google i observer this version has some DUN and PAN problemsa and wifi failures.So.first of all i will upgrade my firmware vesion and will use the latest Android SDK version for developement. Thanks